# A Puzzle For A Mystery

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

First

> You are sitting at your desk, looking for a puzzle to do. You are bored with all the normal puzzles everywhere and are looking a unique puzzle. A true challenge. Just as you think this, a piece of paper with a message flies onto your desk...

**SECOND OF ALL, THE MESSAGE**

> listen. I'm presenting to you a puzzle in this message. A great puzzle. But, the puzzle leads to a mystery. Try to solve the puzzle to get a great prize. a QUESTION no one has been able to answer. a jackpot, if you will. A huge mystery that you can have the pleasure of thinking about. ABUNDANCE of thought you might have, and it will be great. Tricky this puzzle might be, but the reward is well worth it, even though it is almost surely unsolvable. A 8-ball would do no better on the mystery than you. G'Luck, my friend.

Comment: Spelling/Grammar intentional?

Comment: @n_palum yes, me can english :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ankoganit found out,

> "second of all, the message" is a hint to take the second letter of every sentence in the message. This gives `imgurQhjBr8L`, which leads us to [an Imgur URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufPcX.jpg).

That gives us a message:

> "It was so organized... and now it's a mess...
>
>  qkqkmojjxgbwqnqdywcfackjqjkwaajqkkoklabyawqmzqzanqxqmnzzqenwyalaqakxycamlyfmfmqfqbkanlkoffwyo"

After *heavy* hinting in chat, I got the next step:

> Look at each letter individually. Shift it by the number of times it appears in the message. This gives 18 letters, which anagram to the final answer: **FFAO'S SLEEP SCHEDULE**.

Comment: Ffao doesn't sleep so what's so mysterious about it?